# Can't save mysql dump file to my hard drive from a java progam

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm using the following command in a java program (other files are correctly copied to new folders):

```
String cmd = "c:\\wamp64\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.7.36\\bin\\mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --databases test > c:\\mydumps\\test.sql;
```

Nothing is saved to mydumps folder with the following statement:  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

But if I run the cmd string at a command prompt, the test.sql file is saved to mydumps folder.
I'm using Apache Netbeans 12.6 and Java 17.0.2 on Windows 10.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Redirection is a shell construct.  `Runtime#exec()` does not invoke the shell.  Use `ProcessBuilder` to set up the redirection yourself.

Comment: That's what I needed.  If anyone else is inerested, this works:

Comment: ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();

Comment: builder.command(("cmd.exe", "/c", cmd);
builder.start();